# Ajax alert error (Fatal error Class not found in home/../test.php)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site and trying to make recieve data from a range slider with ajax. 
In my alert(data) I get the following error:

*Fatal error Class not found in /home/../...etc/..etc/test.php on line 3*

test.php:

```
<?php

class acf_field_number_range extends acf_field
{
    (...)
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function (e, data) {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "text",
           url: "../wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/fields/number_range-v4.php",
           data: { minValue: data.values.min, maxValue: data.values.max },
           async: false,
           success: function(data){
              alert(data)
           },
           error: function(xhr) {
                     alert('fail') // if your PHP script return an erroneous header, you'll land here
           }
        });
    });

</script>
```

When I use GET I can see it's getting the right values, so that's working. But why do I get the Class error in the alert box? Thanks!

**Edit**

*The Ajax URL is refering to the test.php*

**Edit**

Please for a better explanation see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488180/ajax-alert-error-fatal-error-class-not-found-while-page-works-fine

Comment: you should look on line 3 in the test.php file

Comment: do you have the html code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call is calling a PHP page which returns a PHP error. You should open test.php and check line 3. You are most likely calling a class that doesn't exist (is not declared) or the class is declared in a file, which is not included.

Most class calls look like this:

```
$c = new MyClass(); // Create a class object
```

or

```
MyClass::myMethod(); // Static call to a class method
```

These both will throw the above PHP error if `MyClass` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Line 3 is *class acf_field_number_range extends acf_field*  I pretty sure it has the right class.

Sorry I edit the post.. the code you see above is *test.php* the Ajax refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

You must `include` the page which has the `Class acf_field`

By using `include or require or include_once or require_once`

Before `using` or `extend` it.